# CSS after selector as clamp effect over image

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've try to made in CSS a "clamp effect".

**See image:** 
https://s27.postimg.org/j6m72z5kj/h_transylvania.png

I do not know exactly how this effect is named, so I called him "clamp effect".

Can someone tell me why **::after** does not working?(to can have that "clamp effect" - see link with the image).

**My code:**

```css
h2 {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
img.mypicture {
  width: 230px;
}
.recomandded {
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
top: 125px;
left: 1px;
color: #fff;
background-color: #ff0047;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: 700;
font-family: Lato,Arial,sans-serif;
padding: 3px 16px 3px 6px;
border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.recomandded::after {
content: "";
display: inline-block;
border: 6px solid #dd0843;
border-bottom-color: transparent;
border-right-color: transparent;
position: absolute;
top: 29px;
left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h2>Beautiful Flower</h2>
<img class="mypicture" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fe/Frangipani_flowers.jpg" />
<div class="recomandded">RECOMMENDED</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An absolute element will relate to it's parent only if it's in non static, default, position, therefore I've added `position: relative` to the container, in the example.

I've also fixed the required definitions to match the provided example image.

Here is the fixed CSS:

```
h2 {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
img.mypicture {
  width: 230px;
}
.recomandded {
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
top: 125px;
left: 8px;
color: #fff;
background-color: #ff0047;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: 700;
font-family: Lato,Arial,sans-serif;
padding: 3px 16px 3px 6px;
border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.recomandded::after {
content: "";
display: inline-block;
border: 6px solid #dd0843;
border-bottom-color: transparent;
border-left-color: transparent;
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
left: 0;
}
```

Or have yourself a [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/kqLzyczo/)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you Shahar for your help! Your solution working.